# How to determine request scheme, contextpath if tomcat server is running behind reverse proxy

Tags: java, reverse-proxy

I am building a plugin for a web application in java which is running on Tomcat and behind a apache reverse proxy server.

I am able to get the following:

```
Host Name : request.getLocalName()

Port: request.getLocalPort()
```

How can I get the following for original request, not for proxy request:

**Request Scheme : ??**

**Context Path: ??**

Answer (score 0):

To get the authentication scheme used to protect the Servlet you can call from class `HttpServletRequest` the method `getAuthType()`.  This will return values matching the static finals as specified in the javadocs.

```
Field Summary:
  static String BASIC_AUTH 
    String identifier for Basic authentication. 
  static String CLIENT_CERT_AUTH 
    String identifier for Client Certificate authentication.
  static String DIGEST_AUTH 
    String identifier for Digest authentication. 
  static String FORM_AUTH 
    String identifier for Form authentication.
```

To get the context path you would just call `getContextPath()` of HttpServletRequest.

**EDIT:**

To get the local machine name of the server behind the proxy you could get the localhost machine name:

```
java.net.InetAddress localMachine = java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost();
```

Comment: My web application is running behind revese proxy. SO, request.getContextPath() will return the context path of the proxy url (which is on the address bar), not for the original address, to which proxy server has forwarded the request.

Comment: @DheerajKumarAggarwal See my EDIT in the answer above.  This will tell you the machine name of the server that the request was forwarded to that is behind the proxy.

Comment: @mapple_shaft Thanks, but I just need the scheme name (whether http or https) and context path, regarding Host name, I am already able to determine through request.getLocalName()